# pip3 can't download the latest tflite-runtime

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, tensorflow-lite

The current version of `tflite-runtime` is `2.11.0`:

https://pypi.org/project/tflite-runtime/

Here is a testing for downloading the `tflite-runtime` to the `tmp` folder:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/test
cd /tmp/test

echo "tflite-runtime == 2.11.0" > ./test.txt

pip3 download -r ./test.txt
```

**Here is the error:**

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tflite-runtime==2.11.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tflite-runtime==2.11.0
```

**Here is the pip3 version:**

```
# pip3 --version
pip 22.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.10)
```

What's wrong in the above `pip3 download`? Why can't it find the latest version? And how to fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tflite-runtime 2.11.0 released packages: https://pypi.org/project/tflite-runtime/2.11.0/#files

Python 3.7, 3.8 and 3.9. Only Linux, different Intel and ARM 64-bit architectures. No Python 3.10 and no source code.

Use Python 3.9 if you don't want to [compile from sources](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/build_cmake_pip).

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the Classifiers for `tflite-runtime` on https://pypi.org/project/tflite-runtime/, the only Python versions supported are 3.7, 3.8 and 3.9. You are using Python 3.10, hence `pip` cannot find a version of the package to match it.

Answer (score 1):

***Update to the answer: For those that might run into this issue in the future***

**Error still persist:**
Python 3.10 has been added to the list of supported versions of Python for `tflite-runtime version 2.13.0`, if you look at the Classifiers for `tflite-runtime` on the package website [here](https://pypi.org/project/tflite-runtime/) but the error still persists.

Error message(s):

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tflite-runtime (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tflite-runtime
```

Solution:
Here is a nice solution that works posted here on Stackoverflow:

- For those running Debian Linux or a derivative of Debian (including Raspberry Pi OS), you should install from our Debian package repo. This requires that you add a new repo list and key to your system and then install as follows:

```
echo "deb https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt coral-edgetpu-stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/coral-edgetpu.list
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3-tflite-runtime
```

- For those with other type of systems, you can install by running this command:

```
pip3 install --extra-index-url https://google-coral.github.io/py-repo/ tflite_runtime
```

You can check the original answer out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62749168/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-tflite-runtime) on Stackoverflow.

Credit to the original author of the answer [Unmitigated](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9513184/unmitigated)